# pactl module-loopback loaded every time computer is turned on

Tags: bashrc

The pactl module module-loopback is loaded every time I turn on my computer. I'm not sure why, but I always have to use pactl unload-module 20 (for some reason the module is always id 20).

Is there somewhere I accidentally turned this on or some bash login script I accidentally put this in? Where can I look to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some places come to mind where you may want to look for loading of the loopback-device:

- Have a look at your `/etc/pulse/default.pa` or in case you have defined it for a local user in `~/.pulse/default.pa` to comment out this line ***if present*** like this:

  ```
  # load-module module-loopback <optional parameters>
  ```
- Check with **paprefs** (if installed) whether we have ticked the option *"Loopback audio to local speakers"* in the Mulicast/RTP settings tab.
- You may have made a setting like *"Monitor of..."* in **pavucontrol**.
- There may be or may have been another application installed that needs the loopback module to operate (search for any possible application that may come into consideration).

Comment: Thanks, it was in /etc/pulse/default.pa . I must have put it in there and forgotten about it.